# how to distinguish between real execution from module importation in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

the title might be confusing so here's what I mean, let's say I have this script

information.js

```
const a = () => console.log('a')
const b = () => console.log('b')
module.exports.b = b

a()
b()
```

(notice the `module.exports` of `b` because this function is so cool I want to make it available in my workspace)

`node information.js` outputs `a\nb` as expected.

Now let say I want to import the `b` in another module. In order to simulate this behavior I just run `node` on the command line and type `const {b} = require('./information.js')`. `b` is imported correctly but I still have the output `a\nb`.

What condition should I wrap `a();b()` with in `information.js` so it does not get executed when the file is used for module importation ?

Comment: `if (!module.parent) {` looks promising

Comment: This is XY problem. If you need to use this function separately, create a separate module for it.